# Matrix to Matrix sequence architecture

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

My training data is the set of X{m x n} matricies, which have corresponding Y{m x n} output.It is like unknown function: Y = F(X) and I need to predict Y values based on X.
Cells of matrices can only have values (0,1,2).

Currently the best results for me ( acc: 0.817 , test_acc: 0.801) was provided by next snippet: ( format is 9x9 matrix -> 81 vector, train set is 100,000 samples)

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(81, 9, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(162, 9, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(9, 9, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_training_data,test_target_data),shuffle=True)
```

However after 10 epoch, this model starts overfitting.

Moreover with matrix size (256x9) accuracy is very low (~0.38) and degrades with every epoch after 5.In this case model is seriously underfitting (2/3).

I had also tried using fully-connected solution.But results are pretty similar.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(324, input_dim=81, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(162, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(81, activation='relu'))
```

These things are also provide no result.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.1))
```

I was looking in such things as U-net and GAN, however I really don't think I need such things as batch size, filters, odd dimensions and so on.

Maybe there are any AutoML solutions exist for this case?

Comment: How are your matrices structured? Does position/neighborhood convey any meaning?

Comment: Firebug, The adjacent elements are not connected in any way.Structurally, the simplest analogy would be that each cell value is a decimal place of a number. Rows are numbers, and columns are digits from 1 to 10^column number.
For example [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]] -> 10 + 2 + 0 = 12

Comment: Well, a lack of structure leads me to believe that the matrix representation does not add to the task. Vectorizing the whole matrix would keep the same (non)structure. But your analogy actually has structure, since position is intrinsically linked to magnitude. Perhaps it would be better if you clarified your task a bit more on the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to drastically improve accuracy: 1 (~9.9997) for both sets by just swapping to Conv2D with channel size 1(empty channel like grayscale image)

```
input_shape = (None, size_y, size_x, 1)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel,padding="same", activation="relu", strides = 1, input_shape=input_shape[1:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16 , kernel, padding="same",  strides = stride, activation="relu"))
```

You will need to  reshape [m,n] matrix to [batch_size, m, n, channel(empty)] via this code:

```
training_data = tf.expand_dims(training_data, axis=-1)
```